# How do I responsibly dispose of spoils from a grease trap with mixed automotive and cooking oils?

Tags: plumbing, disposal

Given this grease trap or grease interceptor:

[image: Grease interceptor dirty]

How does one responsibly clean it, and dispose of the material? What if has automotive oils in it as well?

Comment: I would look for someone local with a waste oil furnace who can burn it for heat. If you don't know anyone in your area you could put a note on Facebook marketplace.

Comment: Watch your town/city/county websites and community boards (eg Facebook local moms groups) for hazardous waste disposal events.  My county one will take anything.  This looks small enough that you could put it in a good plastic container and take it in your car to an event.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger make that an answer I'll tick it.  Given this is in the ground, and probably has contaminated it, I would suggest it as best answer .... although probably most expensive by 10,000%.

Comment: For that small of an amount, it's not worth the effort to recycle, just throw it away in a sealed bottle.

Answer (score 5):

This is jurisdiction dependent. In Montgomery County, Maryland, USA, the recycling center at the Shady Grove Processing Facility and Transfer Station (a.k.a., the county dump), [lists related items](https://www2.montgomerycountymd.gov/DepHowDoI/search.aspx) including:

> motor oil - used car oil, used engine oil, used motor oil

and

> cooking oil - bacon fat, hamburger grease, vegetable oil

and the all-inclusive:

> household hazardous waste - acids, air fresheners, ant killer, antifreeze, brake fluid, cleaning products, drain cleaners, driveway sealer, ez pass, fertilizers, gasoline, gas-oil mixes, and kerosene, herbicides, household hazardous waste, insecticides, lawn and garden chemicals, lead products, lighter fluid, mercury-containing thermometers and thermostats, mineral oil, paint thinners and solvents, pepper spray, pesticides, photographic chemicals, sewing machine oil, swimming pool chemicals, transmission fluid, weed killers, yard chemicals

Check your local city/county/state and see if they have something similar.

Answer (score 2):

My son has an auto shop and he has a guy come around every week and pick up old oil.  You should stop in an auto shop in your neighborhood and get the name of who they use.

Answer (score 1):

You call the suction truck guy and tell him what you have, he will tell you the price.

Or as that trap looks kind of small you could perhaps suck it all into a barrel and call the suction truck later when you have a few barrels full, you may want to check on if you're allowed to store that stuff first.